# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `method_name' for #<Object>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am getting undefined method 'xyz' for #. 'xyz' is a instance method written inside ABC Class. Calling the method using delayed job although the object exists. Why I am getting this error. Please anyone help me.

Code Snippet:

```
device_obj.delay(run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).get_device_battery_status
```

In Device model:

```
def get_device_battery_status # Used in delayed Job
  command_data = {"mode"=>"get_battery"}
  self.send_command(command_data)
end
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet.

Comment: Can you please share your code of your Class and instance method and the job.

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Comment: Where is method `xyz`?

Comment: Did you define handle_asynchronously :get_device_battery_status in your model?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna what you posted is same as the code snippet in the question.